how to fix issues with package.json and package.lock.json files out of sync when deploying fiirebase cloud functions?
I am having several issues with deploying a firebase cloud function. I created a new folder, I have node js installed and I have all the necessary files when I open up the project in visual studio code including (package.json, package.lock.json, gitignore etc). When I try installing dependencies it creates new package.json and package.lock.json files instead of using the original. It then gives me errors saying the dependencies don't exist in the files and that my files are out of sync. I've never had this issue before. I've deployed similar cloud functions without an issue.
I tried reinstalling the firebase cli but it didn't take. I was wondering if anybody had a workaround to this.

Are you sure you're calling npm i some-package inside the functions/ folder? Otherwise it will create package.json and node_modules in your root folder (which is not what you want). It will work locally, but when you deploy, the contents from your functions/ folder are used (and that package.json will not be configured correctly)

Your question should include the exact steps you're taking so that anyone can follow them and reproduce the same behavior.  Please edit the question to include that, starting with the creation of a new project.  Without that, we can't see what you might be doing wrong.

@maganap yes that was the reason I kept doing the outer directory. Thanks.
